# Vtiger Automatic login issue without entering the credentials

Tags: php, smarty, vtiger

I am facing issue of automatic logging in to the Vtiger crm 6.2.0. When I am hitting the crm url, instead of asking for login it redirects to vtiger crm home page, without any authentication . AS per [this post](https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/34558/how-could-i-make-a-auto-login/p1), there is no credentials configured in config.inc.php file

Answer (score 1):

Use below for vtiger 6+

http://192.168.1.9:820/index.php?module=Users&action=Login&return_module=Users&return_action=Login&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD

in previous version, variable name for username and pwd was different.